# how to make react native liquid animation with curve

Tags: react-native

[Video description of the idea](https://streamable.com/3ho3n)

I wanna make swipe animation as shown in the above video. BUT I don't know how to make a side of the view to be curved and animate it. So far I have achieved curve from where it can be draggable but don't know how to proceed further from it.

I have used d3-shape but don't think it's gonna work.

I know I can make it draggable using pan responder but what about animation effects around the circle which is being swiped?

Any idea of how should I implement it?

Comment: Could you add some sample code so we can see what you've got so far? My best bet from what you've written is have a function to define the curve that separates the images, pixels greater than the function are drawn from the first image; pixels less than the function are drawn from the second image.

Comment: No, I have 2 view. one on top of other just like tinder swiping cards. both are positioned absolute. and first one was give margin right 10. So it will display 10px part from slider beneath first one.

To draw that circle, i used this repo : https://snack.expo.io/@git/github.com/wcandillon/can-it-be-done-in-react-native:bonuses/tabbar

And then animated svg path based on pan responder applied to circle between that curve.

Comment: @ravi:
It doesn't work, I tried to make changes but it doesn't work the same.
Link: https://snack.expo.io/B1lCgJBF3S